# Mysql procedure givnng error unknown column Age

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here is my Mysql Query

```
    DELIMITER $$

USE `divineproposal_db`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `pr_Search_Profile`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `pr_Search_Profile`(IN vGender CHAR(1),IN vMinAge INT,IN vMaxAge INT,IN vReligion INT)
BEGIN
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), cpl_DateofBirth)), "%Y")+0 AS Age FROM tbl_candidateprofile
            WHERE  Age>= vMinAge AND Age<=vMaxAge;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Error ::**

```
Unknown column 'Age' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use an alias in a `WHERE` clause so you will have to either use a subquery or reuse the definition for `age`:

```
select Age
from
(
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), cpl_DateofBirth)), "%Y")+0 AS Age 
  FROM tbl_candidateprofile
) src
WHERE  Age>= vMinAge 
   AND Age<=vMaxAge;
```

Or:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), cpl_DateofBirth)), "%Y")+0 AS Age 
FROM tbl_candidateprofile
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), cpl_DateofBirth)), "%Y")+0>= vMinAge 
  AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), cpl_DateofBirth)), "%Y")+0<=vMaxAge
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use like this-

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_candidateprofile
            WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), cpl_DateofBirth)), "%Y")+0>= vMinAge AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), cpl_DateofBirth)), "%Y")+0<=vMaxAge;
```

What you are using is not allowed in Mysql